# gapi.client.request() does this function take the same arguments in both v2 and v3?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to migrate from google drive api version v2 to v3. I am using javascript.

---

gapi.client.request() does this  function take the same arguments  in both v2 and v3?
i am sending request for creating a folder in google drive.How it will be in v3

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  you might want to start with https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v3versusv2 followed by https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample piece of code where you are finding the problem ? Could you also specify better what your problem is indicating your actual vs desired output? Thanks !